# tesseract-ocr not recognized by alpine docker container

Tags: docker, tesseract, alpine-linux

I am trying to install tesseract-ocr to use within a docker container, but when I feed a request to my api, I still get an error saying "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract'"

I'm trying to maybe add tesseract to my ENV $Path variable in the Dockerfile, but I'm unable to locate where this tesseract package is even installed. Below I've added my Dockerfile, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
RUN apk add --update --no-cache tesseract-ocr
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.4-cuda10.1-cudnn7-devel
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install .
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/examples/classification
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: have you tried it without --update?  `apk update  && apk add --no-cache tesseract-ocr` ?