# TesseractNotFound issue when containerizing in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, tesseract

**Problem:**

I had `tesseract` installed in local machine and its path is at `/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/bin/tesseract`. Everything works perfectly until I containerized it in docker with error message as: *pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: is not installed or it's not your PATH*

**What I've tried:**

Based on the error message, this is what I've tried:

1). Add PATH in docker desktop app under file sharing to `/usr/local` and mount the file path from local to docker - still getting the error message (doesn't work)

2). Move `tesseract.exe` from where it resides to current local working dir - still getting the error message(of course it doesn't work - what was I even thinking back then?)

3). Modify dockerfile to install tesseract with its dependencies. Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache tesseract-ocr
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt ./ 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
# install dependencies 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade PyMuPDF
# bundle app source 
COPY . /app

COPY ./ChaseOCR.py /app
COPY ./BancAmericaOCR.py /app
COPY ./WellsFargoOCR.py /app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["python3", "MainBankClass.py"]
```

Under requirements.txt file, **pytesseract** and **tesseract** dependencies are also included. - still getting the error message (doesn't work). Being stuck on this issue in the past 2 days and  kinda running out of options here. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415915/tesseract-ocr-not-recognized-by-alpine-docker-container) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820821/tesseractnotfounderror-two-docker-container-python-app-docker-compose) both don't work on my case. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Neo's solution and I am testing it now but its running very slowly. Thus I thought it would be better to share requirements.txt file here just in case other issues are non-related to tesseract.

**requirements.txt:**

```
numpy
pandas
opencv-python
Pillow
Image
pytesseract
tesseract
PyMuPDF
python-levenshtein
tabula-py
```

**Local file dir:**

```
testdockerfile
├─ .vscode
│  └─ settings.json
├─ BankofAmericaOCR.py
├─ ChaseOCR.py
├─ Dockerfile
├─ MainBankClass.py
|- __init__.py
├─ WellsFargoOCR.py
└─ requirements.txt
```

**EDIT 2:**

Just for future reference if anyone has the same issue as I did after implementing `tesseract` in docker and still getting **TesseractNotFound** issue. What you need to do is to comment out `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/path/to/your/tesseract` if you set the path to run it locally. After that, you also need to re-build the image and run that image in docker. It should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 3:**
Some of the python packages in `requirements.txt` have other prerequisites.
With this `Dockerfile` it went successfully through the entire build process.

The trickiest part was to build `opencv`.
*Credits to https://github.com/janza/docker-python3-opencv/blob/master/Dockerfile*

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── requirements.txt
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        wget \
        unzip \
        yasm \
        pkg-config \
        libswscale-dev \
        libtbb2 \
        libtbb-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libtiff-dev \
        libavformat-dev \
        libpq-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install numpy

WORKDIR /
ENV OPENCV_VERSION="4.1.1"
RUN wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip \
&& unzip ${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip \
&& mkdir /opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/cmake_binary \
&& cd /opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}/cmake_binary \
&& cmake -DBUILD_TIFF=ON \
  -DBUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
  -DWITH_CUDA=OFF \
  -DWITH_OPENGL=ON \
  -DWITH_OPENCL=ON \
  -DWITH_IPP=ON \
  -DWITH_TBB=ON \
  -DWITH_EIGEN=ON \
  -DWITH_V4L=ON \
  -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
  -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3.7 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") \
  -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3.7) \
  -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3.7 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
  -DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3.7 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
  .. \
&& make install \
&& rm /${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip \
&& rm -r /opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION}
RUN ln -s \
  /usr/local/python/cv2/python-3.7/cv2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so \
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.so

RUN apt-get --fix-missing update && apt-get --fix-broken install && apt-get install -y poppler-utils && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr && \
    apt-get install -y libtesseract-dev && apt-get install -y libleptonica-dev && ldconfig && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 && apt install -y python-opencv

COPY ./requirements.txt ./ 
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
# install dependencies 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Build:

```
docker image build -t my-awesome-py .
```

Run:

```
docker run --rm my-awesome-py tesseract
Usage:
  tesseract --help | --help-extra | --version
  tesseract --list-langs
  tesseract imagename outputbase [options...] [configfile...]

OCR options:
  -l LANG[+LANG]        Specify language(s) used for OCR.
NOTE: These options must occur before any configfile.

Single options:
  --help                Show this help message.
  --help-extra          Show extra help for advanced users.
  --version             Show version information.
  --list-langs          List available languages for tesseract engine.
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. I am trying it now.

Comment: well it took too long to build the image and wasn't sure if thats because of requirements.txt file. I will share requirements.txt in edit to be more specific. One thing that I am sure of is only `tesseract` requires local dir. The image is still building as of now and will offer details when its done.

Comment: I only included `pytesseract` and `tesseract` in requirements.txt. Here is the error message after building the image: **Successfully installed Pillow-7.2.0 pytesseract-0.3.4 tesseract-0.1.3
sync /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/tmp/write-set-050086098/diff: input/output error**

Comment: The image build successfully on my end, but without the requirements(~60seconds). I ran a container and it seems that tesseract is installed correctly. Editing my answer. I'll try to find some time and reproduce with the requirements.

Comment: Please allow me to re-run it without the requirements and will update you on it shortly

Comment: Built successfully with pytesseract and tesseract in requirements. Editing again the answer to the latest successful build

Comment: Building now with full requirements.txt that you added in the edit of your question. Haven't seen it earlier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219015/discussion-between-neo-anderson-and-liamsuma).

Comment: I would have upvoted this thousand times if I could. Neo is very knowledgable and I really appreciated your help mate